How to change the timeout between incorrect password attempts in SDDM?
When entering a password, either in terminal or on login screen (in my case SDDM), the default timeout between incorrect attempts is around 2 or 3 seconds. I want to change it to something lower as I routinely mistype passwords, mainly due to a different keyboard language being selected at that moment.
I tried changing /etc/pam.d configs, notably system-auth and password-auth, due to them being only ones containing any mention of pam_faildelay.so.
I replaced:
auth required pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
with:
auth required pam_faildelay.so delay=200000
But to no effect.
I also tried setting FAIL_DELAY to 1 in /etc/login.defs, but it didn't help either.
Most of the guides I found either mentioned the config files not found in my system (Fedora 39 KDE), like /etc/pam.d/common-auth, or mention lines which I don't have in the existing configs.
I was able to remove the timeout completely for console logins adding nodelay to pam_unix.so, as described in the answer to another question, but I would prefer a small delay for console logins, rather than no delay at all. And this also didn't affect SDDM login timeout in any way, so...
What am I missing here?
